# Can i draw more then one shape onto picturebox using method below(windows form)

Tags: .net, windows

Im working on my MDI paint-like project.
If i draw shapes using

```
    elementKojiCrtamo.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(odabranaBoja), Convert.ToInt32(toolStripTextBox2.Text)), rect);
```

i can draw as many of them i want, but they are erased when i minimize child form, or if i put another child form over it.

If i draw them using

```
    Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x, y, e.X - x, e.Y - y);
    }
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = buffer;
```

i can draw just one which is not erased if child is minimized. So is there a way to draw more then one using code like this, or some other way to preserve drawings after child form is minimized.

This is one of my first windows form projects so if the answer is obvious be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, which you encounter is normal. Because when you move something on top of your drawing surface, or you hide your form, you effectively make it repaint. And if your paint event doesn't know that you have something on the surface, it will repaint a default image, which is a flat color set in your control property or inherited from form.

So, if you want your drawing to stay, you have to repaint it on `Paint` event. For this you may need to track what has been painted on your surface and then do it again in order.

I am sure that, also, there is a way to save the content of your surface rectangle and then put it back.

Also, when it comes to controls there is custom draw mode. I think, if you select that, your control will automatically repaint things you tell it to paint

You should find this useful http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp/applicationdesign/lesson13.htm

Answer (score 0):

This normal because the you hold only the last shape.
Hold your shapes in array (i.e. `List<Shapes>`) and every time you add a new shape add it to the list
Then in the OnPaint event loop over this list and draw each shape.